# A call to API in Flutter doesn't load the required JSON the first time app is loaded - Flutter

Tags: ios, api, dart, cross-platform, flutter

I was recently learning to code in flutter and was building an app using it on iOS. Therefore, I wanted to build one with the NASA APOD API involved in it.

I have created a simple UI and set a card with Image view which will load the image after passing the url from the API's JSON.

The JSON:

```
{
"copyright": "Panther Observatory", 
"date": "2006-04-15", 
"explanation": "In this stunning cosmic vista, galaxy M81 is on the left surrounded by blue spiral arms.  On the right marked by massive gas and dust clouds, is M82.  These two mammoth galaxies have been locked in gravitational combat for the past billion years.   The gravity from each galaxy dramatically affects the other during each hundred million-year pass.  Last go-round, M82's gravity likely raised density waves rippling around M81, resulting in the richness of M81's spiral arms.  But M81 left M82 with violent star forming regions and colliding gas clouds so energetic the galaxy glows in X-rays.  In a few billion years only one galaxy will remain.", 
"hdurl": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0604/M81_M82_schedler_c80.jpg", 
"media_type": "image", 
"service_version": "v1", 
"title": "Galaxy Wars: M81 versus M82", 
"url": "https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/image/0604/M81_M82_schedler_c25.jpg" },
```

Now I get the URL from this JSON and convert it to a string and pass it to the `Image.Network` function.

When I run the app the first time. The image doesn't load and throws me an error[image]

Well but after I hit the Refresh button on the Visual Studio Code debugger console 
[image]

The code will run and give me the desired output.[image]

So the problem is first time the app is loaded it always throws an error saying that the url is not defined, but after refreshing the app the image and all the data loads from the API call. 
What could be the error in this situation. I think it is something that is related to the state on Flutter. Any help is appreciated.!!

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  StateApodCall createState() => new StateApodCall();
}

class StateApodCall extends State<Home> {
  final url = "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY";
  List resBody;
  String imageUrl;
  String imageTitle;

  Future<String> getAPODData() async{
    var res = await http
    .get(Uri.encodeFull(url), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});

    var resBody = json.decode(res.body);
    print(resBody);
    print(resBody["copyright"]);
    imageUrl = resBody["hdurl"];
    imageTitle = resBody["title"];
    print(imageUrl);
    return "Success!!";
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getAPODData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
        gradient: new LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            const Color(0xFF1ca2e3),
            const Color(0xFF1450a3)
          ],
          begin: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.5),
          end: const FractionalOffset(0.3, 0.1),
          stops: [0.0, 0.5],
          tileMode: TileMode.clamp
        ),
      ),
      child: new Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF124489),
          elevation: 20.0,
          leading: new IconButton(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {

            }
          ),
          title: new Text(
            "APOD",
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontFamily: 'Poppins',
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
              fontSize: 34.0
              ),
            ),
        ),
        body: new ListView(
          children : [
            new Card(
              elevation: 3.0,
              child: new Column(
                children: [
                  new Image.network(
                    imageUrl,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new Card(
              elevation: 2.0,
              child: new Text(imageTitle),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to fix this. You can simply add a `ProgressIndicator` that will be replaced by the `ListView` when the API call is finished.

```
imageUrl!=null? new ListView(
//build
) : new Center(child:new CircularProgressIndicator()),
```

Do not forget to add `setState()` call when you set the url

```
setState((){
imageUrl = resBody["hdurl"];
});
```

Comment: Wow Thanks a lot! That worked and thanks for the quick reply! :)

Comment: Do you know how to make it a determinate progress bar ! cause they say set the value to non-null but i can't

Answer (score 0):

To solve I added this code in the body of the nested statement!

```
body: imageUrl != null ? new ListView(
      children: [
          new Card(
            elevation: 3.0,
            child: new Column(
              children: [
                new Image.network(
                  imageUrl,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          new Card(
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: new Text(imageTitle),
          )
        ],
    ) : new Center(child:new CircularProgressIndicator(
      strokeWidth: 3.0,
    )),
```

and also included the `setState` function

```
this.setState((){
  resBody = json.decode(res.body);
  imageUrl = resBody["hdurl"];
  imageTitle = resBody["title"];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Android API 28 and iOS 9, these platforms disable insecure HTTP connections by default.

With this change Flutter also disables insecure connections on mobile platforms. Other platforms (desktop, web, etc) are not affected.

You can override this behavior by following the platform-specific guidelines to define a domain-specific network policy. See the migration guide below for details.

Much like the platforms, the application can still open insecure socket connections. Flutter does not enforce any policy at socket level; you would be responsible for securing the connection.

Please read this guide https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android